# Not sure how to write from part of query

Tags: sql

I've been tasked to write a query to pull the following:

Orders entered by Advertisers created since 12/18/2013.

I have this so far, but I'm missing the `FROM` piece.

```
Select 
     WO_STATIONS.station_call_letters as "Station"
     ,WO_ORDERS.ORDER_NUMBER as "Order"
     ,WO_ADVERTISERS.advertiser_name as "Advertiser"
     ,WO ADVERTISERS.TCODE as "Adv Num"
     ,WO_ORDERS.FLIGHT_START_DATE as "Order Start"
     ,WO_ORDERS.FLIGHT_END_DATE as "Order End"
     ,WO_ADVERTISERS.CREATE_DATE AS "ADV CREATED"

FROM 

WHERE
      WO_ADVERTISERS.CREATE_DATE > '12/18/2013'
```

Comment: Post your schema and indicate primary - foreign key relations.

Comment: Could you please indicate which database you are using?

Answer (score 0):

It will probably look a little like this:

```
Select 
     WO_STATIONS.station_call_letters as "Station"
     ,WO_ORDERS.ORDER_NUMBER as "Order"
     ,WO_ADVERTISERS.advertiser_name as "Advertiser"
     ,WO ADVERTISERS.TCODE as "Adv Num"
     ,WO_ORDERS.FLIGHT_START_DATE as "Order Start"
     ,WO_ORDERS.FLIGHT_END_DATE as "Order End"
     ,WO_ADVERTISERS.CREATE_DATE AS "ADV CREATED"

FROM 
     WO_ORDERS inner join WO_STATIONS on WO_ORDERS.StationId = WO_STATIONS.StationId
     inner join WO_ADVERTISERS on WO_ADERTISERS.AdvertiserId = WO_ORDERS.AdververtiserId
WHERE
      WO_ADVERTISERS.CREATE_DATE > '12/18/2013'
```

Does your database tool have a graphical user interface for building queries or views? If so, you can add the three tables to the query tool. If your database has foreign keys, the FROM clause will automatically be created for you by the tool. If not, you can drag-and-drop the primary key of one table to the foreign key of another.

Try these resources for more information on joins:
[Access](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb243855(v=office.12).aspx)
[SQL](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

I would also recommend a good book on SQL, such as: [SQL Step by Step](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0043M56UA)